# Could not execute adb command on the terminal of ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

I have uploaded android sdk to AWS ubuntu 64 bit instance. When i try to run the adb command on ubuntu 64 bit, i get the following error :

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I have successfully added the platform and platform-tools path to PATH variable. But still the error remains ..

Can somebody help solve the issue ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you already solved this?